# jQuery AJAX loads twice

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm programming a site, and I've got a problem.

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('input[type="text"][name="appLink"]').keyup(function() {

    var iTunesURL = $(this).val();
    var iTunesAppID = $('input[name="iTunesAppID"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: jsonURL,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 20000,
        data: { a: 'checkiTunesURL', iTunesURL: iTunesURL, iTunesAppID: iTunesAppID },
        success: function(data) {
            if (!data.error) {
                $('section.submit').fadeOut('slow');
                //Modifying Submit Page
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('input[name="appLink"]').val(data.trackViewUrl);
                    $('div.appimage > img').attr('src', data.artworkUrl512).attr('alt', data.trackName);
                    $('div.title > p:nth-child(1)').html(data.trackName);
                    $('div.title > p:nth-child(2)').html('by '+data.sellerName);
                    $('span.mod-category').html(data.primaryGenreName);
                    $('span.mod-size').html(data.fileSizeBytes);
                    $('span.mod-update').html(data.lastUpdate);
                    $('select[name="version"]').html(data.verSelect);
                    $('input[name="iTunesAppID"]').attr('value', data.trackId);
                }, 600);
                //Showing Submit Page
                $('section.submit').delay('600').fadeIn('slow');
            } else {
                $('.json-response').html(data.message).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //$('.json-response').html('Probléma történt! Kérlek próbáld újra később! (HTTP Error: '+errorThrown+' | Error Message: '+textStatus+')').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.json-response').html('Something went wrong! Please check your network connection!').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Sometimes (randomly) the content fades out-in twice.
Could you let me know what's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check with debugger in chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the page is dynamically generated from javascript,

If you execute the following function twice, then there be two events since it executes twice,
so a better way is to unbind all previus *'keyup'* event and bind it again.

Try this,

```
 $('input[type="text"][name="appLink"]').unbind('keyup').keyup(function() {

 });
```

Comment: A short explanation would be nice.

Comment: Yes, please do if you can! Thanks!

Comment: @MCL Sorry for that, I added explanation

Comment: Hmm, I still can't understand, but never mind, it looks like it works :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh no, it keeps doing that sometimes :/

Comment: It would be helpful if you can show us how you are calling this function,
or try adding 
    return false; 
at the bottom of the event callback function

Comment: It looks like when I delete the content of the `input` and write anything like asdasdasd exactly than I paste the link that reacts with the jSON it loads twice. Chrome inspector shows that the json is loaded twice!

Comment: And other, I think it's in connection with the "non-finished" ajax requests. Because if I'm typing a word, ajax runs every time. And if it finds the commant that'd allows the `fadeOut` it starts it's working, and I think it'll act samely with the non-finished requests